# How to get input from user to find a key within a dicitionary and output its value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm making a simple S-Box in python it contains all possible 3 bit combinations as keys and its encrypted combination as its values.

It will basically take in 3 bits from the user and then run it against the S-Box table I have defined, it will then **find the key that matches the users input bits and output its encrypted value**.

Example code below, not the full code;

```
SBox= { "000": "110","001": "010","010":"000","011": "100" }

inputBits= input("Enter 3 bit pattern: ")

if inputBits == "000":
        print("Encrypted combo: ", SBox["000"])
```

Output:

```
Enter 3 bit pattern: 000
Encrypted combo: 110
```

I want to be able to do this more efficiently, i.e: without having to have an if for every possible combination, something similiar to matching the input string with the key in the dicitonary.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `SBox.get(inputBits)` ?

Comment: You're missing a `)` on your `print` line, that will cause a syntax error.

Comment: You have an extra `"100"` at the end of the dictionary with no key before it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dict.get`

**Ex:**

```
SBox= { "000": "110","001": "010","010":"000","011": "100" }

inputBits= input("Enter 3 bit pattern: ")

if SBox.get(inputBits):
    print("Encrypted combo: ", SBox.get(inputBits))

#OR print("Encrypted combo: ", SBox.get(inputBits, "N\A"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`try .. except` is helpful in this condition

```
SBox= { "000": "110","001": "010","010":"000","011": "100" }

inputBits= input("Enter 3 bit pattern: ")

try:
    if SBox[inputBits]:
        print("Encrypted combo: ", SBox["000"])
except KeyError:
    print("wrong bit pattern")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dict.get()` method has a default argument and the same can be used as a fallback option.

If they key passed by the user is available in the dictionary, then the corresponding value is returned. If they key doesn't exist, then the default argument of the `dict.get()` method is returned.

```
SBox= { "000": "110","001": "010","010":"000","011": "100" }

print(SBox.get(input("Enter the 3 bit pattern: "), "Invalid 3 bit pattern."))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SBox= { "000": "110","001": "010","010":"000","011": "100" }

inputBits=input("Enter 3 bit pattern: ")

if inputBits in SBox:
    print("Encrypted combo: {}".format(SBox.get(inputBits)))
else:
    print("Invalid 3 bit pattern entered")
```

Comment: you are using `if inputBits in Sbox` and the also using `SBox.get()` , it will create more time usage instead of `SBox.get(inputBits)` you can use `Sbox[inputBits]` for more fast than current one